# Milliseconds (!) wait in Batch using no externals?

Tags: batch-file, time-wait

I have searched intensively but have only found wait-tips in batch files in seconds units (the ping approach i.e.).

Since I have a need to wait in between two commands only for something like 10-100 milliseconds, that does not work for me unfortunately.

The wait-time needs not to be "super accurate". In my case, does not make a big difference if it's 10ms or 12/15ms, but it should be able to distinguish between 10 and, say 20.

I wonder if there is a solution, and if in any way possible, using just the windows "on board" commands / tricks as I want to have just the batch for ease of "installation" when using later on another machine.

Comment: I don't think, its possible with a resolution less than 100ms. Try: `@echo off :loop echo %time% goto loop` (sorry, no linefeed in comments, but i think, you know, where to set them). Do you see that even the second digit (10ms) after the comma does not count consecutive? (btw: about 60 to 70 of those echos gives you "about" 100ms - which does NOT mean, 6 to 7 will give about 10ms...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

echo Time before: %time%
echo Wait %1 centiseconds (or more)
call :wait %1
echo Time after:  %time%
goto :EOF

:wait centiseconds
for /F "tokens=3,4 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do set /A sec=1%%a, msec=1%%b+%1
if %msec% gtr 199 set /A sec+=1, msec-=100
set lim=%sec%%msec%
:waitHere
for /F "tokens=3,4 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do if 1%%a1%%b lss %lim% goto waitHere
exit /B
```

The minimum precise wait time entirely depends on the speed of the computer. For example, in my case a wait time less than 5 centiseconds always waits for more time. If I use a wait time from 5 centiseconds on, the timing is precise.

**EDIT**: I slightly modified the program in order to make it more precise with small wait times, it is now precise in my computer from 3 centiseconds on!

You must note that the minimum precise wait time also depends on the size of the Batch file; if the file is large, the minimum precise time increases...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %time% variable and calculate the difference.
In pseudo code it looks like this.

```
set startTime=%time%

:wait
set now=%time%
if now-startTime < waitTime goto wait
```

Btw externally programs will not work here, as the loading/starting time is not predictable and can be much longer as your waittime.

Comment: will experiment with the answers. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

this might do, what you want:

```
@echo off
echo %time%
for /L %%i in (1,1,50) do ( echo %time% )>nul
echo %time%
```

for example three consecutive runs:

```
C:\>t
12:15:20,74
12:15:20,75

C:\>t
12:15:21,22
12:15:21,22

C:\>t
12:15:21,69
12:15:21,71
```

As you see, the first run gives you "about" 10ms, the second run gives you "about" 0ms, the third one gives you "about" 20ms.
Nothing reliable...

btw: if you replace `echo %time%` with `echo time` it's getting worse...

Comment: Thanks! Good info .. will try out!

Comment: (1,1,300) will make things a bit more reliable: 50...80 ms